# Selenium webdriver. No redirection after open url

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

When I open manually url there is a redirection to the same url with query parameter. For example:

> https://www.example.com ->
>   https://www.example.com/?queryParameter=someValue

When I open https://www.example.com with C# (IE, FF and CR) webdrivers there is no redirection to one with parameter (in fact sometimes it happends in CR and more rarely in IE but never in FF).

Do you know any workarounds without adding this parameter in code?

Comment: what do you have in the address bar? is it source url or the one with param?

Comment: I have url without parameter in automatic test. If I put the same one manually into another instance of browser (not opened by selenium), it redirects me with url with query parameter

Comment: Do you perform some actions right after your website was loaded? If yes, could you put in your code some stupid pause like Thread.Sleep() after url navigation and see what happens?

Comment: I do driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url), with debuger and after this line no redirection happens. 
But if I put manually in another instance of browser the same url (without parameter), paramener will be added automatically. If I use the same instance of browser that is created by selenium and put the same url without paramenter, result will be the same as in test - parameter is not added.

Comment: How website which you're loading performs a redirection? Is it some javascript code?

Comment: Yes, I disabled javascript and redirection did not work at all. Good idea to deternime the way for investigations